# How to create a VLC Lua extension that does something at particular timestamps?

Tags: lua, vlc

For example, let's say I want to run `vlc.audio.set_mute(true)` at 10 seconds into the current video file and `vlc.audio.set_mute(false)` at 20 seconds (thereby muting seconds 10 through 20).

I have the basic structure of the script down, but I keep running into the issue of how to wait for the moment to take the action.

- Lua itself does not have a built-in sleep function
- Calls to the OS seem to be blocked.
- Busy waiting in a loop causes the extension to be perceived as unresponsive (and it's bad anyway).
- `vlc.misc` is not available in Extensions, so I can't do something like a `while` loop and then run `vlc.misc.mwait(vlc.misc.mdate() + 500)` at the end of each iteration.